# Why is Roblox saying this is an error even though nothing looks wrong?

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to get a custom inventory system but for some reason it keeps saying there is an "error" in my code, i try one, it fails, then i try the other one, it is ok, but then after i add another bit of code, it says that is an error, and this time none of the methods are working

I tried everything there is to do this, it just doesn't work, this is what I have right now:

```
local sel = script.Parent.Parent.Frame.Selected
function update()
    local sample = game.ReplicatedStorage.inventory.Sample
    local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
    local char = player.Character
    local items = player:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Backpack"):GetChildren()
    local btn = nil
    while script.Parent:FindFirstChild("item") do
        script.Parent:FindFirstChild("item"):Destroy()
    end
    if char:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Tool") then -- where it for some reason has an "error"
        table.insert(items, char:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Tool"))
    end
    for i, v in pairs (items) do
        if v.ClassName == "Tool" then
            btn = sample:Clone()
            btn.Name = "item"
            btn.Item.Value = v
            btn.Sel.Value = sel
            btn.Parent = script.Parent
            btn.Image = v.TextureId
        end
    end
end
while true do
    wait(0)
    if script.Parent.Parent.Visible == false then
        update()
    end
end
```

Comment: nvm I fixed it I just needed to put a `wait(1)` before making it start updating the inventory